# Taking JSON sub arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am quite confused with JSON, I can easily take first level arrays values, but having problem with subs.

I am using $.getJSON and code is

```
$.getJSON('http://www.authenticjobs.com/api/?api_key=4c4f1d5934d66ca872dfa2a0cfd3a20b&method=aj.jobs.search&perpage=3&format=json&callback=?', function(data) {
var listings = "";    

$.each(data.listings.listing, function(index, listing) {

    listings += "<li><strong>" + listing.company.name + "</strong> needs a <a href='" + listing.url + "'>" + listing.title + "</a>";

        if (listing.location != "") {
            listings += " in " + listing.location;
        }

    listings += "</li>";

});

$("#authentic-jobs ul").append(listings);

});
```

Visual data is here: http://cloud.ignatynikulin.com/2v0F2p2x111r0X3k4441

I can't get company location name.

I ve tried listing.company.location.name but it's not working and also don't make any sense.

Thank you!

Answer will be (thank you GregL):

> Since listing.company.location is a nested object (visualised by the
>   {} in the picture you attached), so you just want to check if the
>   object is not something like undefined, null or similar (what are
>   called "falsey values" in Javascript).

Comment: Can you post how your array is formed? I am unable to view your image.

Comment: `listing.company.location.name` would be correct, according to your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I created a jsFiddle that works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kAk7c/1/).

The key is to use:

```
    if (listing.company.location) {
        listings += " in " + listing.company.location.name;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking I have to check if there is a data inside location with != "".

Comment: @ignaty Not quite, since `listing.company.location` is a nested object (visualised by the `{}` in the picture you attached), so you just want to check if the object is not something like undefined, null or similar (what are called "falsey values" in Javascript).

Comment: I think I should start to learn plain Javascript instead jQuery only. Any good books for that since we are still talking here. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, depends if you know the basic syntax and want more solid understanding, or if you still need to know the basics. *Javascript: The Good Parts* by Douglas Crockford is a great book that will help steer you towards good JS practises. There are other helpful websites as well. I like the [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/) and the [Mozilla Dev Centre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is apparently good. Plenty of others as well. It's definitely something I recommend doing!

Answer (score 0):

```
listings += " in " + listing.company.location.name;
```